How to draw a red vertical line in center over image in terminal bash?
Sometimes, I need to make pixel-perfect HTML markup. This involves exporting a full-page JPG image of the page, importing it into GIMP, drawing a red vertical line in the center, exporting the image, and optimizing it.
Is it possible to do this through a set of terminal commands?

Since you have the tag ImageMagick, you can do the following with it in a bash script:
convert x: in.jpg
width=$(convert in.jpg -format "%w" info:)
height=$(convert in.jpg -format "%h" info:)
let w=width/2
convert in.jpg  -fill red  -draw "line $w,0 $w,$height"  -quality 75%  out.jpg

The first line grabs the X11 cursor for you to click on a window that is showing
the html (e.g. a browser), and captures it as a jpg image to file in.jpg (or you can start
with that file).
The next lines find the width and height of the image, and set w to
half the width.
The last line draws the wanted vertical line, and the -quality option can
be used to reduce the file size.

Really cool, man, thanky very much.
I changed a bit.
file_path=$(fzf) file_name=$(basename $file_path) file_extention="${file_name##*.}" new_file_name="${file_name%.*}_center.${file_extention}" width=$(convert $file_path -format "%w" info:) height=$(convert $file_path -format "%h" info:) let w=width/2 convert $file_path  -fill red  -draw "line $w,0 $w,$height"  -quality 75%  $new_file_name 

With v7 ImageMagick, there is no need to use the shell to calculate the position of the line, ImageMagick can do it for you very simply all in one command using fx expressions:
First make a 640x480 black image to play with:
magick -size 640x480 xc:black image.png

Now draw a red vertical line down the middle in a single command:
magick image.png -fill red -draw "line %[fx:int(w/2)],0 %[fx:int(w/2)],%h" result.jpg



Just for fun, here's how to make the line thicker and also horizontal:
magick image.png -stroke red -strokewidth 15 -draw "line 0,%[fx:int(h/2)] %w,%[fx:int(h/2)]"  result.jpg


And, here's how to do both in one go:
magick image.png -stroke red -strokewidth 2         \
   -draw "line 0,%[fx:int(h/2)] %w,%[fx:int(h/2)]"  \
   -draw "line %[fx:int(w/2)],0 %[fx:int(w/2)],%h" result.jpg


